# Mathematical functions in Jewish Halacha

Tags: halacha-theory, science, mathematics

What mathematical operators, functions, and constants are mentioned in the Halachah besides addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division?

For example: powers and square or other roots, Pi etc.

Comment: I think you may need to narrow the scope of this question. There are all sorts of fractions that abound. Start with *ma'aser* - that's a fraction! I don't think halacha deals with imaginary numbers unless you care to call the amount of grain that Yosef stored for the eventual famine an "imaginary" number.

Comment: @DanF I don't think there are so many, after all. I don't mean 1/2 and 1/3 and 2/3 etc. Just simple fractions, but not decimals for example.

Comment: Decimals are fractions.

Comment: @Heshy Decimals are part of the decimal system, not just fractions.

Comment: @AlB no, decimals are really just fractions. It's just a shorthand notation for fractions whose denominator is a power of 10 since those are commonly used

Comment: You can read about many mathematical constants used in Judaism at the ongoing [tag:mi-yodeya-series] where we have covered hundreds of mathematical constants already

Comment: @DoubleAA Those are simple numbers. By constants I mean constants like Pi not numbers.

Comment: Pi is definitely a number too and 12 is definitely a constant. Have you taken high school level math? College level?

Comment: Isn't any number considered a "constant"? I think you mean rational vs. irrational - that's a different story. If that's what you mean, edit that into your question.

Comment: Well, sometimes you need nontrivial math. Mishna: If there are 40 seahs of suitable water in a mikvah, and a seah of unsuitable liquid is put in, and then a seah of the resulting mixture is removed, the mikvah is still valid [Mikvaot 7:2]. This may be repeated until the majority of the liquid in the mikvah is unsuitable. [Yevamot 82b] 

Question:How many times can you repeat this process before the mikvah becomes unsuitable?  Answer: You can repeat the operation up to a number of times equal to the largest integer smaller than n, where n is given by:   40x(40/41)^n = 20.  So n=28.

Comment: [Duplicate ?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22870/16706)