# How much non-water liquid invalidates a mikvah

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, mikvah-ritual-bath, water, bitul-batel-null

According to Halacha, if one has an otherwise kosher mikvah, and then a foreign liquid (not water) spills into it, how much of it would have to exist to invalidate the mikvah? What proportion would it have to be that the foreign liquid could become bittul?

Sources appreciated.

Comment: Refer to the 7th chapt of Mishnah Mikvaos

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/133333/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquids other than water such as wine will render a *mikvah* non-kosher if they change its appearance.

(Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 201:25)